# NuGet update-package in VSTS build task

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to update all NuGet references in my solution to the latest version during the build process in VSTS.

So I am wondering how to call "update-package" in a VSTS build task.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Nuget update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#update) command by using Command Line step/task, for example:

1. Add Nuget.exe to source control and map to build agent
2. NuGet Installer step/task
3. Command Line step/task (Tool: `$(build.sourcesDirectory)\Tools\nuget.exe`; Arguments: `Update WebApplication2.sln`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesDirectory`))
4. Other steps/tasks

Comment: thanks! I tried your suggestion, but "nuget.exe Update" needs authentication for my VSTS package feed. And -UserName <username> -Password <password> is not accepted. (Log: "Unknown option: '-UserName'")

Comment: But for the nuget.org feed (with anonymous access) it works. Now I need to make that work for my internal feed. Any ideas?

Comment: @ThomasMutzl Add Command line step (Tool:[Nuget tool path]; Arguments: sources add -name myfeed -source [feed url] -username [xxx] -password [xxx] -StorePasswordInClearText. If you are using VSTS feed, you need to specify the Nuget.config (Include your internal feed) for Nuget install step. By default Nuget.config is in %AppData%/Nuget folder in your machine.

Comment: appreciate your help! Though it still doesn't work. Adding credentials in step 2 worked. Calling Update in step 3 is still unauthorized.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1.) NuGet restore 
-> "OK"

Comment: 2.) Command task: 
##[command]d:\a\1\s\nuget.exe sources add -Name "SampleGet" -Source "https://myname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/SampleGet/nuget/v3/index.json" -UserName <username> -Password <pw> -StorePasswordInClearText
-> "Package Source with Name: SampleGet added successfully."

Comment: 3.) Command task:
##[command]d:\a\1\s\nuget.exe Update d:\a\1\s\MyProject.sln -ConfigFile d:\a\1\s\MyProject\sampleget.config
-> Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'd:\a\1\s\MyProject\MyProject.csproj', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Please provide credentials for: https://myname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/SampleGet/nuget/v3/index.json
UserName: Password: WARNING: Unable to load the service index for source https://[...]index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: @ThomasMutzl Does sampleget.config file contains your feed with username and password? The command line task (nugget.exe sources add) will add the source to %AppData%/Nuget/nuget.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' under Options...